# Compare several dates same column different rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this.

```
+----+------+-----------+
| ID | NAME |   DATE    |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | A    | 1/1/2009  |
|  2 | A    | 1/2/2009  |
|  3 | A    | 1/5/2009  |
|  4 | B    | 2/2/2010  |
|  5 | B    | 2/10/2010 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

Now I need to write a query which will display the below result.

```
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | NAME |   DATE    | DIFF_DATE |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | A    | 1/1/2009  | 1         |
|  2 | A    | 1/2/2009  | 3         |
|  3 | A    | 1/5/2009  | NULL      |
|  4 | B    | 2/2/2010  | 8         |
|  5 | B    | 2/10/2010 | NULL      |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am trying to calculate the different between dates for each user from the oldest to the newest.
for example: Name: A DIFF_DATE:1/2/2009 - 1/1/2009=1 
after that Name: A DIFF_DATE:1/5/2009 - 1/2/2009=3
and so on. If the Date is the max date for the user it will show NULL or 0

Any idea how to creat such a query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for fixing the table!

Comment: I've already done it for you.

Comment: Added a paragraph to try and make it clearer.

Comment: I'm MySQL. I have no idea what a "1/1/2009" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*,DATEDIFF(TAB1.DATE1,A.`DATE`)
FROM TABLE A,(SELECT NAME, MAX(`DATE`) DATE1 FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME) TAB1
WHERE A.NAME=TAB1.NAME;
```